# No qualifying bean of type 'javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory' available for OSGi Application

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, osgi

I am working on a Maven OSGi bundle that incorporates JPA (through [EclipseLink](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/)) and when I deploy the bundle into the OSGi container (Virgo), I receive the following error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory' available
```

The class in question that causes the error is:

```
@Configurable
@Entity
@Table(name = "SCHEDULE")
@RooJavaBean
@RooToString
@RooJpaActiveRecord(versionField = "", table = "SCHEDULE")
@RooDbManaged(automaticallyDelete = true)
public class Schedule {

    @PersistenceContext
    transient EntityManager entityManager;

    ...
}
```

Both the `persistence.xml` and `orm.xml` files have been placed in the `src/main/resource/META-INF` directory. The contents of the `persistence.xml` file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="PGSQLPersistence" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="eclipselink.target-database" value="org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.PostgreSQLPlatform"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="none"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode" value="database"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.weaving" value="static"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.connection-pool.default.initial" value="1" />
            <property name="eclipselink.connection-pool.default.max" value="64" />
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="INFO"/> 
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level.sql" value="INFO"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.parameters" value="false"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.exceptions" value="true"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.logger" value="ServerLogger"/>
        </properties>
        ...
        <class>com.syncsort.dp.xsb.persistence.jpa.entities.Schedule</class>
        ...
    </persistence-unit>

    <persistence-unit name="PGSQLTESTPersistence" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="eclipselink.target-database" value="org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.PostgreSQLPlatform"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="drop-and-create-tables"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode" value="database"/>  
            <property name="eclipselink.weaving" value="static"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.connection-pool.default.initial" value="1" />
            <property name="eclipselink.connection-pool.default.min" value="64" />
            <property name="eclipselink.connection-pool.default.max" value="64" />
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="INFO"/> 
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level.sql" value="FINE"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.parameters" value="true"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.exceptions" value="true"/>
        </properties>
        ...
        <class>com.syncsort.dp.xsb.persistence.jpa.entities.Schedule</class>
        ...
    </persistence-unit>

    <persistence-unit name="DERBYPersistence" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="eclipselink.target-database" value="org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.DerbyPlatform"/>
           <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="drop-and-create-tables"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode" value="database"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.weaving" value="static"/>
        </properties>
        ..
        <class>com.syncsort.dp.xsb.persistence.jpa.entities.Schedule</class>
        ...
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

Likewise, the contents of the `orm.xml` file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entity-mappings version="2.3" 
    xmlns="http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/orm" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/orm http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/eclipselink_orm_2_3.xsd">

    <named-query name="Node.findByNodeName">
        <query>...</query>
    </named-query>

    ...

    <persistence-unit-metadata>
        <persistence-unit-defaults>
            <delimited-identifiers/>
        </persistence-unit-defaults>
    </persistence-unit-metadata>
</entity-mappings>
```

The JPA-related dependencies and Maven bundle configuration (`maven-bundle-plugin` contents) included in the `pom.xml` file are as follows:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>com.springsource.org.aspectj.runtime</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>com.springsource.org.aspectj.weaver</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.roo</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.springframework.roo.annotations</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.9.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.9.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.9.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.9.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.cache</groupId>
        <artifactId>cache-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.9.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.9.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.core</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.asm</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.antlr</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.11.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.10.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.transaction-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.jdo</groupId>
        <artifactId>jdo-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>com.springsource.net.sf.cglib</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.9.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.9.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
        <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
        <version>10.8.2.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.4.1208-jdbc42-atlassian-hosted</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.6</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<plugins>
    ...
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <configuration>
            <instructions>
                <Import-Package>
                    javax.sql,
                    org.aspectj.lang.annotation,
                    org.aspectj.internal.lang.annotation,
                    org.springframework.beans.factory.config,
                    org.springframework.core,
                    org.springframework.core.io.support,
                    *
                </Import-Package>
                <Require-Bundle>
                    org.eclipse.persistence.antlr,
                    org.eclipse.persistence.asm,
                    org.eclipse.persistence.core,
                    org.eclipse.persistence.jpa,
                    javax.persistence,
                    org.springframework.orm
                </Require-Bundle>
                <Export-Package>com.syncsort.dp.xsb.persistence.jpa.daoImpl</Export-Package>
                <Bundle-SymbolicName>com.syncsort.dp.xsb.persistence.jpa</Bundle-SymbolicName>
            </instructions>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

The Spring bean XML (contained in `src/main/resource/META-INF/spring/`) definitions are as follows:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.1.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd">

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:database.properties"
       ignore-resource-not-found="true" ignore-unresolvable="true" /> 

    <bean class="com.example.encryption.EncryptedPropertyOverrideConfigurer">
        <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true" />
        <property name="ignoreInvalidKeys" value="true" />
        <property name="location" value="classpath:database.properties"/>
        <property name="properties" ref="database.props" />
    </bean>

    <context:spring-configured/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.syncsort.dp.xsb.persistence.jpa.*">
        <context:exclude-filter expression=".*_Roo_.*" type="regex" />
        <context:exclude-filter expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"
            type="annotation" />
    </context:component-scan>

    <bean class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close" id="database">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="url" value="${database.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${database.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />    
        <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true" />
        <property name="testOnReturn" value="true" />
        <property name="testWhileIdle" value="true" />
        <property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="1800000" />
        <property name="numTestsPerEvictionRun" value="3" />
        <property name="minEvictableIdleTimeMillis" value="1800000" />
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
        id="entityManagerFactory">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="database" />
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="${database.persistence}" />        
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" id="transactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="${database.persistence}" />        
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj" transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
    <context:annotation-config />
    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy />
    ...
    <bean class="com.example" name="schedule" scope="prototype" />
</beans>
```

Lastly, there is a `database.properties` file in `src/main/resource/META-INF/spring/` that contains the following:

```
database.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
database.url=jdbc\:mysql\://localhost\:3306/<hidden>
database.username=<hidden>
database.password=<hidden>
```

Am I making a configuration or wiring mistake somewhere that is causing the `EntityManagerFactory` not to be created or wired correctly upon deployment?

Thank you for the help.

---

**Aside**

I have also attempted to follow [A Guide to Hibernate with Spring 4](http://www.baeldung.com/the-persistence-layer-with-spring-and-jpa) and include the following in the definition of `org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean`:

```
<bean id="myEmf" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    ...
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

I follow through and added all of the OSGi bundles that go along with the `HibernateJpaVendorAdapter` class (e.g. hibernate-core, hibernate-osgi, etc.) and that led back to the same error as above.

---

**Full Stack-Trace**

```
[2018-04-03 10:24:55.356] start-signalling-18          <DE0006E> Start failed for plan 'example-app' version '2.0.0'. org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'autoUpgradeImpl': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.example.persistence.dao.ExampleDAOException: Error creating bean with name 'com.example.persistence.jpa.entities.Schedule': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:137)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1620)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
    at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.access$1600(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:57)
    at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext$4.run(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:322)
    at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.util.internal.PrivilegedUtils.executeWithCustomTCCL(PrivilegedUtils.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.completeRefresh(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:287)
    at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.extender.internal.dependencies.startup.DependencyWaiterApplicationContextExecutor$CompleteRefreshTask.run(DependencyWaiterApplicationContextExecutor.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.agent.dm.ContextPropagatingTaskExecutor$2.run(ContextPropagatingTaskExecutor.java:95)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.example.persistence.dao.ExampleDAOException: Error creating bean with name 'com.example.persistence.jpa.entities.Schedule': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory' available
    at com.example.persistence.jpa.aspect.ExceptionAspect.analyze(ExceptionAspect.java:312)
    at com.example.persistence.jpa.aspect.ExceptionAspect.exceptionAnalyzer(ExceptionAspect.java:229)
    at com.example.persistence.jpa.aspect.ExceptionAspect.afterThrow(ExceptionAspect.java:132)
    at com.example.persistence.jpa.daoImpl.ScheduleSQLDAOImpl.listAll_aroundBody18(ScheduleSQLDAOImpl.java:324)
    at com.example.persistence.jpa.daoImpl.ScheduleSQLDAOImpl.listAll(ScheduleSQLDAOImpl.java:1)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
    at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.service.importer.support.internal.aop.ServiceInvoker.doInvoke(ServiceInvoker.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.service.importer.support.internal.aop.ServiceInvoker.invoke(ServiceInvoker.java:60)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:133)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:121)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.service.importer.support.LocalBundleContextAdvice.invoke(LocalBundleContextAdvice.java:57)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:133)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:121)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1552.listAll(Unknown Source)
    at com.example.autoupdate.ScheduleUpgrade.copySchedulesToMongodb(ScheduleUpgrade.java:39)
    at com.example.autoupdate.ScheduleUpgrade.upgradeSchdules(ScheduleUpgrade.java:59)
    at com.example.autoupdate.ScheduleUpgrade.upgrade(ScheduleUpgrade.java:67)
    at com.example.autoupdate.AutoUpgradeImpl.upgrade(AutoUpgradeImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:311)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:134)
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.example.persistence.jpa.entities.Schedule': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory' available
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:357)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBeanProperties(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:386)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.wiring.BeanConfigurerSupport.configureBean(BeanConfigurerSupport.java:141)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.aspectj.AnnotationBeanConfigurerAspect.configureBean(AnnotationBeanConfigurerAspect.aj:63)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.aspectj.AbstractDependencyInjectionAspect.ajc$afterReturning$org_springframework_beans_factory_aspectj_AbstractDependencyInjectionAspect$2$1ea6722c(AbstractDependencyInjectionAspect.aj:88)
    at com.example.persistence.jpa.entities.Schedule.<init>(Schedule.java:41)
    at com.example.persistence.jpa.entities.Schedule.entityManager_aroundBody0(Schedule.java:47)
    at com.example.persistence.jpa.entities.Schedule.entityManager(Schedule.java:1)
    at com.example.persistence.jpa.entities.Schedule.findAllSchedules_aroundBody4(Schedule.java:57)
    at com.example.persistence.jpa.entities.Schedule.findAllSchedules(Schedule.java:1)
    at com.example.persistence.jpa.daoImpl.ScheduleSQLDAOImpl.listAll_aroundBody18(ScheduleSQLDAOImpl.java:316)
    ... 49 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveNamedBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:996)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findDefaultEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:579)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:546)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$PersistenceElement.resolveEntityManager(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:707)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$PersistenceElement.getResourceToInject(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:680)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata$InjectedElement.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:169)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:354)
    ... 60 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Could you post the full stack trace?

Comment: Yes. I have updated the question to include the full stack trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found was to circumvent the JPA portion of the bundle I was creating and directly create a `HibernatePersistenceProvider`:

```
EntityManagerFactory factory = new HibernatePersistenceProvider().createEntityManagerFactory("persistenceUnitName", null);
```

This does not solve the issue itself but removes the issue of resolution entirely. My suspicion is that OSGi and JPA are not being configured correctly in our environment and therefore, OSGi cannot find any `EntityManagerFactory` instances to inject.

Answer (score 0):

I'm hazarding a guess at this but you have two persistence units defined, `name="PGSQLPersistence"` and `name="PGSQLTESTPersistence"`.

I think you need to specify which PU you want to use in your `@PersistenceContext` annotation, e.g. `@PersistenceContext(unitName = "PGSQLPersistence")` although I would have expected a slightly different exception thrown as a single PU cannot be automatically determined.

Comment: I made that adjustment, and now the error is: `Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'PGSQLPersistence'` available

Comment: Without seeing the code I'm not entirely sure what else to try. The only other thing I woudl say is that Spring and OSGi don't mix well together although Spring v4 was the last OSGi compatible release I think though I am not entirely sure. I personally do not mix Spring and OSGi as their philosophies differ. Your issue sounds like a classloader issue but I can't be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change unitName attribute on @PersistenceContext by name as suggested by Kerry

Comment: I did, but now I have the following error: `Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'PGSQLPersistence'`. Usually adding the qualifier clears up finding more than one `PersistenceContext`, but it appears as though the configuration is being parsed, but there are no `PersistenceContext` instances at all.